# Cannot see all picklist values in a Translate Settings

Tags: picklist, translation

I have a country field in object Case with 50 picklist values for countries.

I'm creating a Translate operation in settings, I select my desired language, setup component Picklist value, and object Case, and I find my country picklist field.

The problem is that I just can see 20 values from picklist, instead of 50 (all of them). Why I having this issue?

Comment: Please put the "solved" part as an answer. This is a Q&A site.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: It's a 'next page' button on the botton of the page... I think it is not too much user-friendly...